# Arithmatic signs are not working properly in strtotime

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I want to fetch the correct date as per the timezones.

ex. I have a time zone +5:30 from GMT. if GMT is 30 aug 2016 1:00 pm then for gmt+5:30 should give me 30 Aug 2016 6:30 pm however, adding timezones like that actually subtracts it rather adding.

I have this code:

```
$a=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which gives me 2016-08-30 07:36:01 as per GMT which is correct.

```
$b="+5:30";
$c=(strtotime($a.$b));
echo($c);
```

it gives me 30 Aug 2016 02:08:25 which is wrong I should get  30 Aug 2016 13:10:32.

What I mean is, if I am adding the timezone value it is getting subtracted and if I do same with -5:30 as timezone I get the correct result. Can somebody please suggest what am I doing wrong or how this should work actually.

Comment: Since strtotime is a Stringparser it behaves strange sometimes. I would suggest to calculate with timestamps not Dates, or to use DateTime. In DateTime you can Change the timezone and get de Result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTimeZone` and `DateTime` objects to make it more obvious while working with timezone offsets:

```
$a = "2016-08-30 07:36:01";
$b = "+5:30";

$gmtTz = new \DateTimeZone("GMT");
$offset = new \DateTimeZone($b);

$dt = new \DateTime($a, $gmtTz);
$dt->setTimezone($offset);

echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");  // "016-08-30 13:06:01"
```

Comment: @UmeshKaushik, have you tried to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Solution 1 :**

```
$minutesToBeAdded = 330;
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$currentTime = new DateTime($currentDate);
$currentTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutesToBeAdded . 'M'));

$newTime = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dateTime = new DateTime($currentDate);
$dateTime->modify('+330 minutes');
```

**Solution 3 :**

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$newTime = strtotime($currentDate . ' + 330 minute');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime);
```

I think the above solution will be helpful for you though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks man, however, @RomanPerekhrest works well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you use functions like `date` and `strtotime`, PHP converts the inputs you supply according to your `date.timezone` configuration in PHP, which may not be UTC. So it's important to check, or explicitly set, the timezone before you do the conversion.

```
$date = "30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm";

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get()); // gives us "UTC"
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date))); // 2016-08-30 13:00:00

var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date . "+5:30"))); // 2016-08-30 07:30:00
```

So now you're wondering why you just went back in time 5 hours and 30 minutes. Well, if you look at the actual Unix timestamp from `strtotime` the truth is revealed about what `date` and `strtotime` are doing.

```
var_dump(strtotime("30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm"), strtotime("30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm +5:30"));
```

This gives you...

```
int(1472562000)
int(1472542200)
```

In the first case, `strtotime` takes the input string `"30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm"` and converts it to a Unix timestamp under the assumption that we're currently in UTC. In the second case, it takes the input string `"30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm +5:30"`, which already has a GMT offset of +5:30. So it assumes that we're 1:00 PM in GMT+0530, and it tries to convert that back to UTC (i.e +0000), meaning it now needs to subtract 5 hours and 30 minutes to get to UTC, which gives you `"30 Aug 2016 7:30 am"`

It's easier to avoid all this confusion when you use `DateTime`, because you can explicitly specify the timezone or the GMT offset and not be subject to implicit timezone conversion. Also, it's important to note that in PHP a timezone is more than just a GMT offset. PHP uses the [Olson Timezone Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) to reliably and accurately convert date/time information across different timezones, since GMT offsets can actually vary throughout the year in different timezones.

```
// DateTime doesn't try to convert this because you told it what the timezone is
$dt = new DateTime("30 Aug 2016 1:00 pm", new DateTimezone("UTC"));
// now lets try with the offset
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimezone("Asia/Kolkata"));
var_dump($dt->format("j M Y g:i a")); // "30 Aug 2016 6:30 pm"
```

Notice, there's no need for you to actually mess around with how many hours/minutes to add/subtract. PHP figures it all out by looking up the needed timezone information in the database. Because we correctly specified the timezone supplied and the timezone converted we can rest assured we always have the accurate time regardless of how many times we subsequently convert between timezones. It's a far more reliable abstraction than what you're trying to do.